# dojo/on: conflicts in the events

Tags: dojo

Hi I am not familiar with how to pause and resume events.
I would like to pause dijit/select's toggleDropDown method and resume it.
I also have 2 buttons that are used to pause and resume and trigger select's dropdown action.
I have read an [article](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/on.html) in dojo but its baffling me.
Please see my script below

```
<script>
        require([   "dojo/ready",
                    "dojo/_base/fx",
                    "dojo/on", 
                    "dojo/dom",
                    "dijit/TitlePane",
                    "dijit/form/Select",
                    "dojo/_base/window",
                    "dijit/form/Button",
                    "dojo/domReady!"
                ], function(ready, fx, on, dom, titlepane, select, win, Button) 
        {
                 ready(function()
                 {
                    var toggle = true;

                    var myButton = new Button
                    ({
                        label: "Toggle Select Events",
                        onClick: function()
                        {
                            if(toggle)
                            {
                                //true
                                selectTowns.pause();
                                toggle = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //false
                                selectTowns.resume();
                                toggle = true;
                            }

                        }
                     }, "progButtonNode");

                    var myButton1 = new Button
                    ({
                        label: "Trigger drop down",
                        onClick: function()
                        {
                            selectTowns.toggleDropDown();
                        }
                    }, 'dropButtonNode'); 

                    var selectTowns = new select
                    ({
                        name: "select2",
                        options: [
                        { label: "Tennessee", value: "Tennessee" },
                        { label: "Virginia", value: "Virginia", selected: true },
                        { label: "Washington", value: "Washington" },
                        { label: "Florida", value: "Florida" },
                        { label: "California", value: "California" }
                        ]
                    }).placeAt(win.body());

                    on.pausable(selectTowns, "click", clickHandle);

                 });
        });
    </script>
```

Please advise 
Thanks
Clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then this is what your code should look like:

```
require(["dojo/ready",
    "dojo/_base/fx",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dijit/TitlePane",
    "dijit/form/Select",
    "dojo/_base/window",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/domReady!"], function (ready, fx, on, dom, titlepane, select, win, Button) {
    ready(function () {
        var toggle = true;

        var myButton1 = new Button({
            label: "Trigger drop down"
        }, 'dropButtonNode');

        var selectTowns = new select({
            name: "select2",
            options: [{
                label: "Tennessee",
                value: "Tennessee"
            }, {
                label: "Virginia",
                value: "Virginia",
                selected: true
            }, {
                label: "Washington",
                value: "Washington"
            }, {
                label: "Florida",
                value: "Florida"
            }, {
                label: "California",
                value: "California"
            }]
        }).placeAt(win.body());

        var buttonHandler = on.pausable(myButton1, "click", function() {
            selectTowns.toggleDropDown();
        });

        var myButton = new Button({
            label: "Toggle Select Events",
            onClick: function () {
                if (toggle) {
                    //true
                    buttonHandler.pause();
                    toggle = false;
                } else {
                    //false
                    buttonHandler.resume();
                    toggle = true;
                }

            }
        }, "progButtonNode");

    });
});
```

Or check out the fiddle I made here: http://jsfiddle.net/SxXAt/

The first thing I think you missed was that the "pause" and "resume" is meant for the handler that the dojo/on module returns (in my example, it's buttonHandler). This handler that was returned is what can be paused or resumed.

Comment: If I were to change like                                           "var buttonHandler = on.pausable(selectTowns, "change", function()    {            selectTowns.toggleDropDown(); selectTowns.focus();
});". Would it work? It seems that there is no response if there is a change in select after resuming the  selectTowns' event. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/JF9Uy/1/

Comment: The reason why there is no change event firing is that your store data only has "label" and "value". Dojo's Select widget reads when an option with a different "id" is selected. If you change all your "values" to be "id" or just add an "id" to each of your objects in your store, then your code should work

Answer (score 0):

The on.pausable call returns a handler that you will need.  You will also have to define clickHandle as a function in the on.pausable method, like so:

```
var selectHandler = on.pausable(selectTowns, "click", function(evt) {
    console.log("your handler code here");
});
```

And that handler is used with the pause() and resume() methods, not the select box:

```
if ( toggle ) {
    // true
    selectHandler.pause();
    toggle = false;
} else {
    // false
    selectHandler.resume();
    toggle = true;
}
```

So all put together:

```
require([   
         "dojo/ready",
            "dojo/_base/fx",
            "dojo/on", 
            "dojo/dom",
            "dijit/TitlePane",
            "dijit/form/Select",
            "dojo/_base/window",
            "dijit/form/Button",
            "dojo/domReady!"
        ], 
        function(ready, fx, on, dom, titlepane, select, win, Button) 
        {
         ready(function()
         {
            var toggle = true;

            var myButton = new Button
            ({
                label: "Toggle Select Events",
                onClick: function()
                {
                    if(toggle)
                    {
                        //true
                        selectHandler.pause();
                        toggle = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //false
                        selectHandler.resume();
                        toggle = true;
                    }

                }
             }, "progButtonNode");

            var myButton1 = new Button
            ({
                label: "Trigger drop down",
                onClick: function()
                {
                    selectTowns.toggleDropDown();
                }
            }, 'dropButtonNode'); 

            var selectTowns = new select
            ({
                name: "select2",
                options: [
                { label: "Tennessee", value: "Tennessee" },
                { label: "Virginia", value: "Virginia", selected: true },
                { label: "Washington", value: "Washington" },
                { label: "Florida", value: "Florida" },
                { label: "California", value: "California" }
                ]
            }).placeAt(win.body());

            var selectHandler = on.pausable(selectTowns, "click", function(evt) {
                console.log("pausable click");
            });

         });
    });
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. No wonder it is about the handler of the event. But it seem to have problem with var  selectHandler declaration. It's "clickHandle". So I changed to "clickHandler". Again it does not work.  The error stated: "ReferenceError: clickHandler is not defined".

Comment: @user1739825 You may need to make the selectHandler (or clickHandle) a global variable.  Call it window.clickHandler instead and call window.clickHandler.pause() and window.clickHandler.resume().

Comment: @user1739825 I edited the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Thanks again. I made changes according to your changed solution above. Again the error is still the same :- "ReferenceError: clickHandle is not defined" and "ReferenceError: clickHandler is not defined"

Comment: @user1739825 I found out that you need to make clickHandle a function as shown in the newly edited answer.  Even if you do nothing when the select box is clicked, you still need one for on.pausable to work.

Comment: @ Dustin, There is no error. However, toggleDropDown  does not seem to be paused. Clicking on  selectHandler also does not produce logged message too. It seems we do not have a clear idea on how the on.pausable function works.